# Nginx config with multiple AngularJS2 Projects using HTML5Mode

Tags: angular, nginx, location, html5mode

I have a problem with my Nginx configuration. I have two separate angularjs2 projects which should work with one nginx instance. 
The applications are separated into two folder /admin and /webapp.

Now what I'm trying to do is when I call mydomain.com it should open the app in /webapp. If I call mydomain.com/admin it should open the admin application (which is also an angularj2 app).

What I've tried so far is the following:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html/webapp;    
  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  location /admin/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/admin/;
    try_files /admin/$uri /admin/index.html;
  }
}
```

I hope I can get help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html/webapp;    
index index.html index.htm;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location /admin {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.html;
}
```

The `root` directive is preferred over the `alias` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

The `index` directive is inherited and does not need to be repeated.

The `$uri/` terms will encourage `nginx` to append a `/` to the URI of a directory so that the `index` directive works correctly. I also corrected some of your `try_files` terms. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: I've tried to remove /admin/ from try_files and append it to root in "/admin" location but this isn't working. Do you maybe know why?

Comment: Where is `/admin/index.html`? My answer assumes that it is located at `/usr/share/nginx/html/admin/index.html`. The `$uri` variable already includes `/admin/` - so it should not appear in `root` statement.

Comment: Yes it is located there

The file structure looks like this:
/usr/share/nginx/html/
    - admin
    - webapp